# Unity Catalog: use service principal's identity for query table

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

When accessing a blob storage account you can set the following `spark properties` in order to use a service principals identity as described [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/storage/azure-storage.html).

```
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net OAuth
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net <application-id>
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net {{secrets/<secret-scope>/<service-credential-key>}}
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token
```

I would like use the same approach for accessing a unity catalog table: so when executing

```
select * from unitycatalogtable;
```

it should use a service principal's id. Which spark properties do I have to use for that?

Thank you!